# AMD graphics drivers instalation failed

Tags: drivers, upgrade, updates

Hi just try to make an update on my linux machine and after the : sudo apt intall -f  I try an upgrade to see if is something there and i get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libavcodec59 libavcodec59:i386 libavfilter8 libavformat59 libavutil57 libavutil57:i386 libllvm15.0.50502-amdgpu libllvm15.0.50502-amdgpu:i386 libplacebo208 libpostproc56
libswscale6
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
#
# An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
# CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
# Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
#
The following packages will be REMOVED:
amdgpu-dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libavcodec60 libavcodec60:i386 libavfilter9 libavformat60 libavutil58 libavutil58:i386 libllvm15.0.50503-amdgpu libllvm15.0.50503-amdgpu:i386 libplacebo292 libpostproc57
libswscale7 libvpl2
The following packages have been kept back:
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 libgbm1-amdgpu libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
The following packages will be upgraded:
amdgpu-core e2fsprogs evince evince-common gir1.2-gweather-4.0 gnome-initial-setup grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
gst-omx-amdgpu gstreamer1.0-libav language-pack-en language-pack-gnome-en libaio1 libasound2-plugins libasound2-plugins:i386 libchromaprint1 libcom-err2 libcom-err2:i386
libde265-0 libdrm-amdgpu-common libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libext2fs2 libfreerdp-server2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 libgweather-4-0
libgweather-4-common libllvm15 libllvm15:i386 libmozjs-102-0 libnvme1 libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8:i386 libss2 libswresample4 libswresample4:i386 libwinpr2-2 libx264-164
libx264-164:i386 libxatracker2-amdgpu libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 linux-image-6.3.0-7-generic linux-image-generic logsave lsb-release mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless python3-cairo python3-dbus
python3-html5lib python3-setproctitle sysvinit-utils webp-pixbuf-loader
64 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 1 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 92,7 MB/214 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Fetched 92,7 MB in 9s (10,7 MB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 215828 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing amdgpu-dkms (1:6.0.5.50502-1607507.22.04) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic
grep: /boot/config-5.19.0-50-generic: No such file or directory
W: zstd compression (CONFIG_RD_ZSTD) not supported by kernel, using gzip
grep: /boot/config-5.19.0-50-generic: No such file or directory
E: gzip compression (CONFIG_RD_GZIP) not supported by kernel
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--remove):
installed amdgpu-dkms package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
amdgpu-dkms
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea what i can do?

Comment: Packages are built for an OS & specifically release; providing those release details are always helpful for useful advice.  What are you running?

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu Mantic Minotaur (development branch)
Release: 23.10
Codename: mantic   and i am not able to display all the links that i have in error so sorry

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (mantic) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu mantic and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 13 October 2023. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989 Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. For support issues with Ubuntu mantic you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for #ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Comment: ok soo i understood that i use an beta version? how can i change to normal version Ubuntu 23.04 ?

Comment: It's **not** a *beta*, but still **alpha**  (*before freezes & things can change daily, breakage is expected any day etc*).  Ubuntu *mantic* is expected to [reach *beta* on 21 September 2023](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989) which is some distance into the future. Ubuntu has tools to upgrade you to a *newer* release, but not go backwards (*you do that via your own backup procedures*).  You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system non-destructively (*which can allow you to change release*), but *mantic* is off-topic here.

Comment: ohh i see so just because i am here let's say and i find this bug is a good idea to report it and i think i will remain at this version so maybe i can help in the future